# How to install OpenCV with minGW on an offline machine?

Tags: windows, eclipse, opencv, cygwin, mingw

The minGW seems to only have an online installer. How do i do the offline installation, so that i can have an OpenCV+MinGW+Eclipse environment to work?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution i found is by [Stephan T. Lavavej](https://nuwen.net/mingw.html). Although a bulky installation, one can easily install MinGW.